# if wp_query taxonomy term have posts

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

Having formulated my $query for a custom taxonomy on a page template, how would I ask if a specific term has posts?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'exhibitions',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'exhibition',
            'field'    => 'slug'
        ),
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Assuming I'm on the right track, a verbal description of the sort of conditional statements I'm looking for would be:

if the $query taxonomy term 'current' have posts, do something;

elseif the $query taxonomy term 'upcoming' have posts, do something else;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you exactly need, but normally, by default, `get_terms` returns only terms that actually have posts assigned to them

```
$terms = get_terms( 'exhibition' );
var_dump( $terms );
```

Apart from this, I really do not know what you exactly need

Comment: That sounds like it could work. Just for the record, my usage scenario is not ideal. The custom theme I inherited from the previous dev needs to be re-coded so this is part of a temporary workaround: a page which redirects to the correct template with header("Location: ".$exhb_link); depending on which term has posts. First 'Current'. If not, 'Upcoming'. If not, 'Past'.

Comment: It does look quite disjointed, and it confuses me big time. Sorry that I can not help you out.

Comment: I think you did help me, Pieter. I'll test it and mark the working solution as answered.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term). Something like:
Feed your query an array of terms:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'exhibitions',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'exhibition',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms' => array(
              'current',
              'upcoming',
            ),
        ),
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Then loop over it multiple times:

```
if ($query->have_posts()) {
  while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    if (has_term('current','exhibition')) {
      // stuff
    }
  }
}
$query->rewind_posts();
if ($query->have_posts()) {
  while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    if (has_term('upcoming','exhibition')) {
      // stuff
    }
  }
}
$query->rewind_posts();
```

Comment: Thanks, @s_ha_dum, but not quite. This is more like the reverse of checking if a post has terms. I need to check if a query's particular term has posts. I could do it by re-formulating the entire query several times, each time with tax_query ... 'terms' => 'current' then again with 'terms' => 'upcoming' etc. but that seems excessive.

Comment: @simbasounds : see the edit

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I'll try the get_terms method first since it seems like it'll work for my requirements which are very basic.

Comment: `has_term` is what I was looking for as well, thank you, good answer.